# How do I get allegro on Orwell Dev C++

Tags: dev-c++, allegro

I'm not using bloodshed dev c++ , instead I'm using orwell dev c++ , I got Allegro 5 and installed the package (as a .zip file) but it says 'allegro5/allegro.h: No such file or directory'. Maybe I'm using the wrong type of header or is it another problem?Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That means you did not install the Allegro files in the correct place. I´m not familiar with the [GCC Toolchain](http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/) that Orwell uses (Im a Visual Studio guy), but what you need to do is place them on a place where the compiler can find them. Then make a **makefile** with the instructions on how to build this program with the correct Allegro libraries linked.

[Here](https://wiki.allegro.cc/index.php?title=Windows,_Code::Blocks_and_Allegro_5) is the wiki article for installation on Code::Blocks, Maybe it can help you installing on DevC++, however, I think the binaries listed [here](http://download.gna.org/allegro/allegro-unstable-bin/5.1.11/) might be newer than the ones on the Allegro's wiki page.

Comment: I'm really surprised why libraries are this hard to install :( I'm sure you know of the 'check for updates' button in bloodshed but I can't seem to find it on Orwell (I can't post this as a separate question but I need answers), where is it?

Comment: Yes they are hard to install at first but then you see the pattern... Either way, I'm not sure where is the update button there, usually should be on the Help section, if not you can always check from time to time the website to find new versions

Comment: I have tried countless tutorials including the one you recommended me but there's always files missing :-( I have tried getting SDL as an alternative for allegro but both have files missing . I download the exact versions and files the tutorial says to but why does the tutorial mention files/directories tgat I don't have?

Comment: May I know the tutorials you used to try to install allegro? You could try the one I did for Visual Studio [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33557962/allegro-5-visual-studio-2015/33599724#33599724)

Comment: I did the youtube tutorials for allegro and the Cplusplus tutorial as well

Comment: Good news! My SDL header works but I can't run any programs yet because of this error message:C:\Users\fakeUsername\Documents\g++.exe [Error] unrecognized command line option '-static-libgcc-lalleg'

Comment: this is a leftover from a previous tutorial since I remember working with a file called 'lalleg' but how do I get rid of it?

Comment: Delete that part from the proyect's makefile

Comment: I took the lalleg off the command but it still comes up with the message