# Allegro 5 - Unable to open allegro_monolith-debug.libkernel32.lib

Tags: visual-studio-2015, allegro5

I'm trying to use `Allegro 5` on Visual Studio 2015 for the first time using [this guide from SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33557962/allegro-5-visual-studio-2015). However, I cannot run the program, because the compiler can't open/find

> "allegro_monolith-debug.libkernel32.lib"

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Oh my, that is my guide.... ok, that is an option to install Allegro, but it now is kinda deprecated. Allegro now ships as a NuGet package for Visual Studio for hassle free installation and integration with Visual Studio.

Comment: Still... I'll check latter if my original answer you used is still valid and update it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a separator between allegro_monolith-debug.lib and kernel32.lib .